# EntityFramework/LINQ - get filtered content from associated table/type

Tags: linq, entity-framework-4

In my Entityframework model, I have a type/table “ModelElement”, which is linked to a type/table “ElementToComponentMapping”. The navigation/foreign keys are "ModelID" and "ElementNo".

I need to write a method that returns an instance of ModelElement based on certain filtering conditions, where the content of the ElementToComponentMapping linked to the ModelElement instance is also included. The challenge is that I also need to filter on what I return from the ElementToComponentMapping, which means it doesn’t look like I can use .Include

So this doesn't work, as I can't use the included/navigation type in the where clause

```
public ModelElement GetModelElement(int modelID, int modelElementNo, int version)
{
   return (from c in context.ModelElements.Include("ElementToComponentMapping")
           where c.ModelID == modelID && c.ElementNo == modelElementNo 
                && c.ElementToComponentMappings.Where(m => m.version == version)
                   select c).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

My second attempt was to query out the main "ModelElement" object first, then query out the associated "ElementToComponentMappings" separately, and set that as the property of the "ModelElement"

```
public ModelElement GetModelElement(int modelID, int modelElementNo, int version)
{
ModelElement newElement = (from c in context.ModelElements
                   where c.ModelID == modelID && c.ElementNo == modelElementNo
                   select c).FirstOrDefault();
newElement.ElementToComponentMappings = 
                      (from m in context.ElementToComponentMappings
                            where m.ModelID == modelID 
                            && m.ElementNo == modelElementNo 
                            && m.version == version
                                select m).FirstOrDefault();
return newElement;
}
```

But this also doesn't work, as the type returned by directly querying for the "ElementToComponentMappings" object is different from the "ElementToComponentMappings" property on the "ModelElement" object.

This seems like a simple operation - get value of foreign key-linked tables, where you filter on what you get from the content of the FK tables, so hopefully I'm just missing something obvious here...?

Answer (score 1):

The type is different because your `newElement.ElementToComponentMappings` is collection but your query returns only single instance.

You can try to use this:

```
context.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
var newElement = (from c in context.ModelElements
                  where c.ModelID == modelID && c.ElementNo == modelElementNo
                  select c).FirstOrDefault();

var mapping = (from m in context.ElementToComponentMappings
               where m.ModelID == modelID 
                     && m.ElementNo == modelElementNo 
                     && m.version == version
               select m).FirstOrDefault();

// now check if newElement.ElementToComponentMappings contains your single item
```

You can also try to use this:

```
context.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
var newElement = (from c in context.ModelElements
                  where c.ModelID == modelID && c.ElementNo == modelElementNo
                  select c).FirstOrDefault();

((EntityCollection<ElementToComponentMappings>)newElement.ElementToComponentMappings)
    .CreateSourceQuery()
    .FirstOrDefault(m.version == version); // You don't need to check FKs here

// now check if newElement.ElementToComponentMappings contains your single item
```

Neither of these methods works if your type is proxied and lazy loading is enabled because this expected automatic relation fixup will not mark navigation property as loaded (if you have lazy loading enabled next access to the property will trigger lazy loading and load all other entities).

Comment: Thanks for your input, unfortunately not quite there yet: In your first suggestion, where does the newElement.ElementToComponentMappings property get set? In your second suggestion, I get an error that ElementToComponentMappings does not contain definition for FirstOrDefault, and the best extension method overload has invalid arguments. Regarding the type difference, you're right that ElementToComponentMappings is a collection - does that mean I should call ToList instead at some point?

Comment: In the first case it is a trick. If everything is correctly configured you don't need to set that property. It should be automatically populated. In second case it is strange. `CreateSourceQuery` should return `ObjectQuery` which is implementation of `IQueryable` and it offers `FirstOrDefault`. Your way with `ToList` will work only if your entity is not proxied, otherwise you will get some error that you cannot assign a new collection to navigation property.

Comment: +1 for the useful tips, tricks, and insights. In the end it I couldn't get this approach to work, so did it another way.